# How do I use the command line OrgDBOrgSettings tool with CRM Online?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to use the command line [OrgDBOrgSettings tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2691237#bookmark-more) (not the [managed solution-edition](https://orgdborgsettings.codeplex.com/)) to change some values in my instance of CRM Online.

I try to retrieve the current settings with the following command:

```
Microsoft.Crm.SE.OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.exe Retrieve /u myorgname
```

The following error is returned

> Error occurred in OrgDBOrgSettings and the error details are Organization With Name = myorgname Does Not Exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `Microsoft.Crm.SE.OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.exe.config` to have the correct values for CRM Online.

Go to Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources to get the values needed for the config file.

- Change the `OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_CrmDiscoveryService_CrmDiscoveryService` value to your Dicovery Service from Developer Resources (e.g. https://disco.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc).
- Change the `OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_SKU` value to `Office365`.
- Change the `OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_UserName` to your email (e.g. user@org.onmicrosoft.com)
- Change the `OrgDBOrgSettingsTool_OrgServiceUri` to your Organization Service from Developer Resources (e.g. https://org.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc). Do not keep the default `{0}`, since it will otherwise insert the Organization Unique Name there.
- Use the Organization Unique Name from Developer Resources when calling the tool: `Microsoft.Crm.SE.OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.exe Retrieve /u OrganizationUniqueName`

Comment: Great that you found your answer. Recommend you take a look at (consider using) https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell (which  is a great tool that provides a lot of great functionality (including setting system settings).